# Heroku push is being rejected, after reinstallation of OS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github, heroku-toolbelt

I'm following the tutorials made by Michael Hartl, but I tend to distro hop a lot on Linux. I cloned my repo from github and I'm doing good with that. However I can't push to heroku anymore and I'm not sure why exactly...

Here is the commands I'm trying to run:

```
$ bundle exec rake test
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "Use SSL and the Puma webserver in production"
$ git push
$ git push heroku
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Everything works fine up until the last part:

```
git push heroku
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

In Git 2.0, Git will default to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

To git@heroku.com:morning-stream-6357.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:morning-stream-6357.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I'm not really sure how to fix this at all :/ Can someone help? I have researched this and I've added the remote heroku repo using this:

```
git remote add heroku-remote git@heroku.com:project.git
```

Of course to modify it for my code would be like this:

```
git remote add heroku-remote git@heroku.com:morning-stream-6357.git
```

But I'm still not able to push from the command line, I've been pushing using the heroku deploy button that lets me deploy the master branch but I think that's not a good idea otherwise I think it would be mentioned in the book. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: In case anyone is wondering,I did install the heroku tool belt.

EDIT: I should have noted before that I have indeed already tried running this command:

```
git push heroku master
```

But it still gives me an error:

```
jose@jose-desktop:~/Workspace/sample_app$ git push heroku master
To git@heroku.com:morning-stream-6357.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:morning-stream-6357.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I'm not sure what's causing this, it should be up to date. I cloned the repo and I've manually deployed from heroku's github connection before so it should be current.

```
git pull
```

Results in this:

```
jose@jose-desktop:~/Workspace/sample_app$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: Did you pull like it says?

Comment: hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by just the hell with it and creating a new heroku repo via heroku's site then adding the repo:

```
heroku login
heroku git:clone -a whispering-hamlet-1487
```

Unfortunately, this leads to there being "multiple" heroku apps in one directory so to migrate the database as we were supposed to in Listing 7.30 in Micheal Hartl's book it can no longer be migrated using this:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Instead it has to be migrated using:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate -app whispering-hamlet-1487
```

I wrote it out completely in case anyone else learning rails finds this difficult and needs to reference this in the future. You should replace whispering-hamlet-1487 with the name of your app.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to continue using the old repo but to be honest that doesn't really matter it seems like a total pta. It's much better to just give up on this. If someone is aware of a way to do this without having to create a new repo, I'd more than welcome that since I imagine that during production this wouldn't be the best course of action.

Comment: Did you try a git pull heroku master on the old repo?

Comment: Can you explain that to me a bit? When I want to work on my code in another machine should I pull from github or pull from heroku I don't really understand why I shouldn't just pull from github and be done with it how does the process work?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a `git pull heroku master`to merge your heroku changes locally. When you do a `git pull` it is doing `git pull origin master` which is github and not heroku. So whatever changes you've pushed to your heroku are causing a conflict.

Also, you need to set the git matching option from the command line using

- `git config --global push.default matching`

or

- `git config --global push.default simple`.

Those tell git what branch to push instead of needing to be explicitly pushed, such as with the master branch `git push heroku master`. That is what that error message is trying to tell you.

Note: Heroku will only accept your master branch unless you explicitly tell it 
`git push heroku yourbranch:master` https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

This is covered in the Hartl tutorial under section [1.4.1 Installation and setup](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#uid69) you need to do a one time of:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"
$ git config --global user.email your.email@example.com
$ git config --global push.default matching
$ git config --global alias.co checkout
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the branch that you are pushing to Heroku.

try running `git push heroku master` rather than `git push Heroku`.

If you want to push a branch other than master to Heroku then you can do this:

```
git push heroku yourBranchName:master
```

Also - the error message is telling you to `git pull` before pushing again. You should probably do that.